# Over the boundary of the unit cube

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

Evaluate the integral of the vector field $$F(x,y,z)=(xy,y^2,y^3)$$
over the boundary of the unit cube.

My method is to parametrize all the six boundaries of the unit cube in the following way $$P_1=(u,v,0),\quad P_2=(u,v,1), \quad P_3=(0,u,v)..., \quad 0\le u,v\le 1$$
$$P_4=(1,u,v), \quad P_5=(u,0,v), \quad P_6=(u,1,v).$$

then evaluate $F(P_i)$ which i will denote it as $F_i$, and then evaluate $$\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial v}=N_i$$

and finally $$\iint_\limits{S}F\cdot n\,d\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^6\left(\iint_\limits{R}F_i\cdot N_i\,du\,dv\right)$$
It turns out that the region $R$ is just $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, now the problem is that I got $0$ as an answer but the book say it is $3/2$, so is it just a calculation error or my method doesn't work?

Comment: Do you mean "Evaluate the integral of the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)$ over the boundary of the unit cube."?

Comment: You're right @Arthur

Comment: @Yassir your parametrization is fine, at least the one's you have shown. Did you take the correct unit normal vectors? That may be the issue why you got zero.

Comment: The easiest is to just use the unit normal vector as you already know them. For example unit normal vector to $P_1$ surface is $(0, 0, -1)$ and to $P_2$ is $(0, 0, 1)$

Comment: I'm going to add the other ones @MathLover

Comment: Same way for $P_3$ and $P_4$ outward unit normal is $(-1, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 0)$ respectively and for $P_5$ and $P_6$, unit normal is $(0, -1, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$.

Comment: It works thank you @MathLover

Answer (score 2):

You can't parameterize the top and bottom surface as $(u,v,0)$ and $(u,v,1)$ -- that means that your normal vectors $N_1$ and $N_2$ will be equal, and this vector points *into* the cube at one surface and *out of* the cube at the other.

What you're doing ought to *work* once you fix the inconsistent directions of your normals. However, if you have the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) available, you're almost certainly expected to use that instead of integrating over each of the six sides separately. That will be much quicker, especially because the divergence of this particular field is much simpler than the field itself.

Comment: I can't use the divergence theorem because this exercise is before the section of the divergence theorem.